# Apex: Get value from first element of Map

Tags: apex, json, map, deserialize, array

I am receiving the following JSON for a web service:

```
{
  "count" : 1,
  "posts" : {
    "1234567" : {
      "id" : "1234567",
      "private" : false,
      "message" : "New post on Monday Jan 5th",
      "subject_ref" : null,
      "created_at" : "2015-01-05T09:56:59-08:00",
      "story_id" : null,
      "newest_reply_at" : null,
      "reply" : false,
      "subject_type" : null,
      "subject_id" : null,
      "user_id" : "09876543",
      "updated_at" : "2015-01-05T09:56:59-08:00",
      "workspace_id" : "4569872",
      "has_attachments" : false,
      "reply_count" : 0,
      "formatted_message" : "<p>New post on Monday Jan 5th</p>"
    }
  },
  "results" : [
    {
      "id" : "1234567",
      "key" : "posts"
    }
  ]
}
```

It will always just be one record, and I need to access the "id". Since there will always just be one record, I figured I can avoid looping through the map. Unfortunately, I haven't had much luck figuring out how yet.

So far I have the following code:

```
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);  
Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String,Object> posts = (Map<String,Object>)m.get('posts');
```

I'm thinking I need to do something like:

```
String NewMLPostId = posts.keySet().toArray()[0].get('id');
```

But that is not working.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Sets are by their very nature unordered, so you're right that you need to create an array (or iterate) to get the "first" (which is meaningless if your input data is set, you're better off thinking "only").

The array constructor in apex can accept a set, as in `new List<String>(someStringSet)` works just fine.

We can adapt that to your sample code and make it work without a loop (although frankly the loop seems a bit more readable, and more useful in the future if this code gets re-used for bulk operations):

```java
String resBody = '{"count":1,"posts":{"1234567":{"id":"1234567","private":false,"message":"New post on Monday Jan 5th","subject_ref":null,"created_at":"2015-01-05T09:56:59-08:00","story_id":null,"newest_reply_at":null,"reply":false,"subject_type":null,"subject_id":null,"user_id":"09876543","updated_at":"2015-01-05T09:56:59-08:00","workspace_id":"4569872","has_attachments":false,"reply_count":0,"formatted_message":"<p>New post on Monday Jan 5th</p>"}},"results":[{"id":"1234567","key":"posts"}]}';
```

```java
Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resBody);
Map<String,Object> posts = (Map<String,Object>)m.get('posts');
Map<String,Object> firstPost = (Map<String,Object>) posts.get(
    (new List<String>(posts.keySet()))[0]
);
System.debug(firstPost);
```

Answer (score 1):

A Map has a values() method, which returns a List. To adopt the set-up of ca_peterson, without the use of a Set of keys:

```
String resBody = '{"count":1,"posts":{"1234567":{"id":"1234567","private":false,"message":"New post on Monday Jan 5th","subject_ref":null,"created_at":"2015-01-05T09:56:59-08:00","story_id":null,"newest_reply_at":null,"reply":false,"subject_type":null,"subject_id":null,"user_id":"09876543","updated_at":"2015-01-05T09:56:59-08:00","workspace_id":"4569872","has_attachments":false,"reply_count":0,"formatted_message":"<p>New post on Monday Jan 5th</p>"}},"results":[{"id":"1234567","key":"posts"}]}';

Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(resBody);
Map<String,Object> posts = (Map<String,Object>)m.get('posts');
Map<String, Object> firstPost = (Map<String,Object>)posts.values()[0];
System.debug(firstPost);
System.debug(firstPost.get('id'));
```

(... just posting this, because the question is still getting views. Not sure, if "values()" was available at the time of the question.)